# How to select all filtered checkboxes inside ngFor in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an Angular 2 component which loads and shows a list of checkboxes to the user within `*ngFor`, the list can also be filtered based on a key. I need to select all the filtered items and add them to an array. I can check all the checkboxes, but the problem is when I change the `checked` problematically the `change` event does not fire, any idea how to fix this?

template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stringKeyFilter" placeholder="Key Filter"
           [(ngModel)]="keyFilter">
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let device of devices| stringFilter: keyFilter">
        <td>
            {{device.$key}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label> <input type="checkbox"
                               [checked]="selectAll || selectedDevices.indexOf(device.$key) > -1"
                               (change)="updateSelectedDevices(device.$key, $event)" > View</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="selectAllDevices()">Select All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="deselectAllDevices()">Deselect All
    </button>
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'device-list',
    template: template
})
export class DeviceListComponent implements OnInit {
    devicesObservable: FirebaseListObservable<Device[]>;
    devices: Device[] = [];
    isLoading: boolean = true;
    selectedDevices: string[] = [];
    selectAll: boolean = false;
    allCtrl: any;

    keyFilter: string = '';

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {


        this.devicesObservable = this.af.database.list('/online', {
            query: {
                orderByKey: true,
            }
        });
        this.devicesObservable.subscribe((devicesData)=> {
            this.devices = devicesData;
            this.isLoading = false
        });
    }

    updateSelectedDevices(deviceId: string, event): void {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.selectedDevices.push(deviceId);
        }
        else {
            _.pull(this.selectedDevices, deviceId);
        }
    }


    loadingDeviceDetail(loading: boolean): void {
        this.isLoading = loading;
    }

    selectAllDevices(): void {
        this.selectAll = true;
    }

    deselectAllDevices(): void {
        this.selectAll = false;
        this.selectedDevices = [];
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Where are you stuck?

Comment: the problem is when I change the `checked` problematically the change event does not fire

Comment: you have not bound your checkbox with your model. Use ngModel and then it should behave properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

Updated sample code and plunker to demo select/deselect all checkbox for filtered list.

---

According to my understanding, the filter behavior changed from Angular1 to Angular2.

In Angular1, when data or filter parameter is modified, the DOM (webpage) will be recalculated. (I maybe wrong on this, too long ago :P)

In Angular2, in short, modifying the data(array) will not trigger filter calculation, so no new result, no update to DOM.

The long and official explanation is here: [Angular2 Pipes - ts](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html). If you insist on using pipe(filter) within template, you should explore the **impure pipe** section in the document.

Another solution is to not use filter with `*ngFor`. Create a filtered list instead.

### Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/pEpaj0?p=preview

### Sample Code

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  title='How to select all filtered checkboxes inside ngFor in Angular 2?';
  url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703103/';

  device = [
    {'name':'abc','checked':false},
    {'name':'abcd','checked':false},
    {'name':'abcde','checked':false},
    {'name':'abc123','checked':false},
    {'name':'abc1234','checked':false}];

  deviceFilter = '';

  deviceFiltered = this.device.slice(0);

  selectFiltered(){
    this.deviceFiltered.forEach(i=>i.checked=true);
  }

  deSelectFiltered(){
    this.deviceFiltered.forEach(i=>i.checked=false);
  }

  onFilterChange(){
    if (this.deviceFilter.length > 0) {
      this.deviceFiltered = this.device.filter(i => i.name.indexOf(this.deviceFilter) > -1);
      console.log(this.deviceFiltered);
    } else {
      this.deviceFiltered = this.device.slice(0);
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h2><a [href]="titleUrl">{{title}}</a></h2>

<div>
  Filter
  <input [(ngModel)]="deviceFilter" (ngModelChange)="onFilterChange()">
</div>

<div>
  List:
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of device">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="i.checked">{{i.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  Filtered List:
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of deviceFiltered">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="i.checked">{{i.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button (click)="selectFiltered()">Select Filtered</button>
  <button (click)="deSelectFiltered()">Deselect Filtered</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you try to select all the devices, your main list, is not updated, nothing has changed and angular doesn't detect changes on it. (There is an updated flag, but the list is the same). You have two options:

1. Put a flag on every checked element on the list.
2. Trigger a manual render with 
   ApplicationRef.tick()
   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#tick-anchor

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but none of the suggestions would solve my problem, the problem is the filtered items are not reflected in the component so I don't know which items to flag.

Comment: The filter is just a function, why not apply it on the list and then flag items. Somthing like:  `var a = new searchFilter() result = a.transform(this.devices,  this.keyFilter); result.forEach((i)=>{ this.selectedDevices.push(i.$key) })`

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your code may vary as i made some changes to get a working app only. Please get the related part from the code snippets and apply.

Here is the working code for your question.

Below is the changes you need to make into your code.

```
<input type="checkbox"  [checked]="selectedDevices.indexOf(device.$key) > -1"
                               (change)="updateSelectedDevices(device.$key, $event)" >
```

Change your select all function as the following.

```
selectAllDevices(): void {
    this.selectedDevices = this.strFilter(this.devices, this.keyFilter).map(dev=>dev.$key); 
  }
```

Note: `this.strFilter` is the filter function in component class/function.
This depends on your Filter class. I have create filter/pipe like this.

//stringfilter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'stringFilter'})
export class StringFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<any>, filterKey: string): Array<any> {
    return (
      filterKey ? value.
        filter(el => (el.name).toLowerCase().includes(filterKey))
        : value
    );
  }
}
```

In the component class i did like 
//component class

```
import {StringFilter} from './filter-file'
```

And

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.strFilter = new StringFilter().transform;
    //this.devices = [];
    this.isLoading = false;

  }
```

I have tested following code. Hope this solves your problem.